# Function not getting all documents in a collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know there is a similar question that exists here but it doesn't really answer the question on here. My code currently on get the last two documents in a collection.

```
const [recipedata, setRecipeData] = useState([]);
  
    const fetchRecipes = async () =>{
        const response = fire.firestore().collection("recipes");
        const data = await response.get();
        data.docs.forEach(item=>{
            setRecipeData([...recipedata, item.data()])     
        })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
       fetchRecipes();
    }, [])
```

Again when I print (recipedata) it only show two objects in the array. Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your Firestore document.

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct and should fetch all the documents in the collection. You should check the the collection again. Also modifying the code like this should be better so you are updating the recipes array only once.

```
const [recipedata, setRecipeData] = useState([]);
  
const fetchRecipes = async () =>{
  const response = fire.firestore().collection("recipes");
  const data = (await response.get()).docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  
  console.log(data)
  //Updating only once
  setRecipeData(data)     
}
  
useEffect(() => {
  fetchRecipes();
}, [])
```

Please share your collection as well so we can try replicating any issue if it has something to do with Firestore.